# How to write RenderFragment ChildContent in code

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

Following MyComponent.razor:

```
@inherits TableDropDown<ApplicationUser, string>
@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}
@code {
    public MyComponent()
    {
        ValueSelector = item => item.Užívateľ;
        ChildContent = ctx =>
            @<text>
                <ColumnDef TRow="ApplicationUser" Context="user" Width="170px">@user.Username</ColumnDef>
                <ColumnDef TRow="ApplicationUser" Context="user" Width="200px">@user.Name</ColumnDef>
            </text>;

    }
}
```

throws error:

> CS0201    Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new
> object expressions can be used as a statement.

[image]

When I remove the `@` character from the beginning of the lambda, I get:

> CS0103    The name '__builder' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You cannot specify the `TRow` type, it must be deduced from the component's property

Comment: Why? I other components I do it often, why not from @code block?